# Android OpenCV 2.4.9 static initialization not working like the example APK

Tags: android, opencv

Hey I am working with the OpenCV Sample - face - detection I am trying to use static initialization whereby I don't have to download the package manager to get it to work 
I have already added the OpenCV library-2.4.9
I also added the libraries to the libs folder but they are always deleted when I build the app
I also altered the Android Mk file to look like this
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk 

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I also added the static initialization declaration on the FdActivity
this is how it looks

```
package org.opencv.samples.facedetect;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class FdActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    static {
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
    } else {
        Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
    }
}

private static final String    TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";
private static final Scalar    FACE_RECT_COLOR     = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
public static final int        JAVA_DETECTOR       = 0;
public static final int        NATIVE_DETECTOR     = 1;

private MenuItem               mItemFace50;
private MenuItem               mItemFace40;
private MenuItem               mItemFace30;
private MenuItem               mItemFace20;
private MenuItem               mItemType;

private Mat                    mRgba;
private Mat                    mGray;
private File                   mCascadeFile;
private CascadeClassifier      mJavaDetector;
private DetectionBasedTracker  mNativeDetector;

private int                    mDetectorType       = JAVA_DETECTOR;
private String[]               mDetectorName;

private float                  mRelativeFaceSize   = 0.2f;
private int                    mAbsoluteFaceSize   = 0;

private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");

                try {
                    // load cascade file from application resources
                    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
                    File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    os.close();

                    mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (mJavaDetector.empty()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
                        mJavaDetector = null;
                    } else
                        Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    mNativeDetector = new DetectionBasedTracker(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath(), 0);

                    cascadeDir.delete();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade. Exception thrown: " + e);
                }

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public FdActivity() {
    mDetectorName = new String[2];
    mDetectorName[JAVA_DETECTOR] = "Java";
    mDetectorName[NATIVE_DETECTOR] = "Native (tracking)";

    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.fd_activity_surface_view);
    mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    //OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mGray = new Mat();
    mRgba = new Mat();
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mGray.release();
    mRgba.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = mGray.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
        mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
    }

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
        if (mJavaDetector != null)
            mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                    new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    }
    else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
        if (mNativeDetector != null)
            mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
    }

    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
        Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);

    return mRgba;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
    mItemFace50 = menu.add("Face size 50%");
    mItemFace40 = menu.add("Face size 40%");
    mItemFace30 = menu.add("Face size 30%");
    mItemFace20 = menu.add("Face size 20%");
    mItemType   = menu.add(mDetectorName[mDetectorType]);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);
    if (item == mItemFace50)
        setMinFaceSize(0.5f);
    else if (item == mItemFace40)
        setMinFaceSize(0.4f);
    else if (item == mItemFace30)
        setMinFaceSize(0.3f);
    else if (item == mItemFace20)
        setMinFaceSize(0.2f);
    else if (item == mItemType) {
        int tmpDetectorType = (mDetectorType + 1) % mDetectorName.length;
        item.setTitle(mDetectorName[tmpDetectorType]);
        setDetectorType(tmpDetectorType);
    }
    return true;
}

private void setMinFaceSize(float faceSize) {
    mRelativeFaceSize = faceSize;
    mAbsoluteFaceSize = 0;
}

private void setDetectorType(int type) {
    if (mDetectorType != type) {
        mDetectorType = type;

        if (type == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Detection Based Tracker enabled");
            mNativeDetector.start();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Cascade detector enabled");
            mNativeDetector.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting an error crash and the camera does not open here are the log files

```
07-30 11:30:32.989: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): Trying to get library list
07-30 11:30:32.989: E/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): OpenCV error: Cannot load info library      for OpenCV
07-30 11:30:32.989: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): Library list: ""
07-30 11:30:32.989: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): First attempt to load libs
07-30 11:30:32.989: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): Trying to init OpenCV libs
07-30 11:30:32.989: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): Trying to load library opencv_java
07-30 11:30:32.999: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): Cannot load library "opencv_java"
07-30 11:30:32.999: W/System.err(6088): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load   opencv_java from loader    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-  2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-2]: findLibrary returned null
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:64)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:95)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:39)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:56)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.<clinit>(FdActivity.java:32)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-30 11:30:33.029: W/System.err(6088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 11:30:33.029: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(6088): First attempt to load libs fails
07-30 11:30:33.029: D/ERROR(6088): Unable to load OpenCV
07-30 11:30:33.029: I/OCVSample::Activity(6088): Instantiated new class  org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity
07-30 11:30:33.049: I/OCVSample::Activity(6088): called onCreate
07-30 11:30:33.109: D/CameraBridge(6088): Attr count: 3
07-30 11:30:33.109: I/OCVSample::Activity(6088): OpenCV loaded successfully
07-30 11:30:33.109: D/dalvikvm(6088): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-2/libdetection_based_tracker.so 0x420de340
07-30 11:30:33.119: D/(6088): calling hookDlopen()!
07-30 11:30:33.119: D/(6088): calling hookCheckABI2Header()!
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/dalvikvm(6088): dlopen("/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-2/libdetection_based_tracker.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libopencv_java.so" needed by "libdetection_based_tracker.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libopencv_java.so" not found
07-30 11:30:33.119: D/AndroidRuntime(6088): Shutting down VM
07-30 11:30:33.119: W/dalvikvm(6088): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ab8e10)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libopencv_java.so" needed by "libdetection_based_tracker.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libopencv_java.so" not found
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:73)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:133)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)                      

07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-30 11:30:33.119: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me find out how to solve this

Comment: I am facing same issue.Did you find something helpful?

Comment: @user1534409 :-  I'm too facing the same issue.
Please add answer if the problem has been solved..

Answer (score 1):

Please change the path of the

```
../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

to the actual path in your pc where this OpenCV sdk is placed.
like in my system it is

```
/home/onkar_sharma/Documents/OpenCV_Android/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```